# How can I add a third button to an editable in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about the AngularJS editable framework. When using an editable, two buttons appear: the save button and the cancel button. However, I want a third button (with a minus symbol) to delete the text in the editable. How can I add a third delete button?

Here is a fiddle of one of my previous questions:

[Example with only two buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/10362/)

```
<a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think they have support for this right now.
I've done it myself.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

    app.run(function (editableOptions) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    });

    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
            name: 'awesome user'
        };

        $scope.showClear = function () {
            $scope.show = true;
        }

        $scope.empty = function () {
            $scope.user.name = "";
            $scope.show = false;
        }
    });

<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span href="#" editable-text="user.name" ng-click="showClear()">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</span>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="empty()" ng-show="show">
        -
    </button>
</div>
```

Hope this will help :).

Comment: That module is referenced by the quistioner. Please read the question first and follow the jsfiddle provided by the questioner.